# Generic Entity in Spring Data for Couchbase Documents

Tags: spring, nosql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, couchbase

One advantage of Document DBs like Couchbase is schemaless entities. It gives me freedom to add new attributes within the document without any schema change.

Using Couchbase JsonObject and JsonDocument my code remains generic to perform CRUD operations without any need to modify it whenever new attribute is added to the document. Refer [this example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/beersample-java2) where no Entities are created.

However if I follow the usual Spring Data approach of creating Entity classes, I do not take full advantage of this flexibility. I will end up in code change whenever I add new attribute into my document.

Is there a approach to have generic entity using Spring Data? Or Spring Data is not really suitable for schemaless DBs? Or is my understanding is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue the opposite is true.

One way or another if you introduce a new field you have to handle the existing data that doesn't have that field.

Either you update all your documents to include that field. That is what schema based stores basically force you to do.

Or you leave your store as it is and let your application handle that issue. With Spring Data you have some nice and obvious ways to handle that in a consistent fashion, e.g. by having a default value in the entity or handling that in a listener.